# Процедура возвращает только одну запись

Tags: mysql, процедуры

Когда я вызываю процедуру и передаю ей необходимые параметры, она возвращает только одну запись, при том, что в базе их есть несколько.

```
delimiter ~
create procedure ShowRange(in MaxRange int)
begin
declare sId int;
declare sName varchar(50);
declare sType varchar(50);
declare sMaxRange integer;
declare countWeapon int;
declare done integer default 0;
declare ShowRangeCursor Cursor for select model.id,model.name,model.type,characteristics.max_range from model
inner join characteristics on model.id = characteristics.model_id
 where characteristics.max_range = MaxRange limit 1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
open ShowRangeCursor;
while done = 0 DO
fetch ShowRangeCursor into sId,sName,sType,sMaxRange;
select count(model.id)  into countWeapon from model inner join characteristics on model.id = characteristics.model_id
where characteristics.max_range = MaxRange;
if(countWeapon >0) then
select sId as 'ID', sName as 'Name',sType as 'Type',sMaxRange as 'range';
else select 'В таблице не обнаружено записей' as 'Помилка';
end if;
end while;
close ShowRangeCursor;
end~
```

Comment: У вас там курсор... Процедура Вам возвращает последнюю обработанную курсором. Может быть такое, что у последней, обработанной курсором записи, выдается только одна?

Comment: У вас в select в курсоре limit 1 так что она всегда не более одной записи возвращает. И не понятно зачем тут вообще процедура, не вижу в ней ничего такого, чего нельзя выбрать одним запросом

Comment: @Mike Этот лимит ничего не решает. Почему процедура? Потому что на данный момент прохожу практику и так надо.

Comment: @makintosh Как ничего не решает. цикл же из за него выполняется только один раз и его select - это `select sId as 'ID', sName as 'Name',sType as 'Type',sMaxRange as 'range';`  явно выбор одной строки

Comment: И кстати, если цикл отработает N раз то вернется не N записей, а N наборов по одной записи, что в большинстве случаев не одно и то же. Что бы процедура вернула единый набор из N записей они все должны быть выбраны одновременно, одном запросом

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

У вас в `SELECT` в курсоре `LIMIT 1` так что она всегда не более одной записи возвращает. Кроме того, если цикл отработает N раз то вернется не N записей, а N наборов по одной записи, что в большинстве случаев не одно и то же. Что бы процедура вернула единый набор из N записей они все должны быть выбраны одновременно, одном запросом.